# How to reference a variable that is generated in a function to do a .contains() on it in Cypress?

Tags: variables, cypress

How to reference a variable (foo) that is generated in a function to do a .contains() on it in Cypress? Getting "foo is not defined"

To get a randomized variable, used the following function:

```
`cy.get('.row > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(2) > .form-control').click({force:true})
    .type(claim_nbr_Alpha_Numeric())
     function claim_nbr_Alpha_Numeric() {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        return text;}`
```

Then try to select it (text) on the page, used the following on the page:

```
`cy.contains(text).click()`
```

Get the following reference error: "text is not defined"

Answer (score 2):

Your variable "text" is defined, and therefore only available, within the scope of your 'claim_nbr_Alpha_Numeric' function.

The best way to handle this would be to call and assign the result of your function to a variable before your first cy.get() call. Then you can use it in both places.

I.e.:

```
function claim_nbr_Alpha_Numeric() {
    ...
}

var textToType = claim_nbr_Alpha_Numeric();

cy.get(...).click(...).type(textToType);

cy.contains(textToType).click();
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps however, is it possible to get the initial value returned from the function claim_nbr_Alpha_Numeric() and store that as opposed to calling the function again and regenerating a new value?

Comment: @SteveMandel sorry I'm not sure I understand what your asking? The code sample above only calls the function once. It all depends on where you declare and use your variables. If you declare your function and call it to textToType at the top of your file, rather then in each test it() bloc, it will only generate one value.